# React Native - Dynamic link not persisting through install process

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a small React Native app for which I have a series of Firebase dynamic links. When the app is installed, the links work perfectly in directing users to the relevant screen defined in the dynamic link

However, if the user does not have the app installed when the dynamic link is followed, the route defined in the dynamic link does not persist.

Is it possible to persist the deep link during the installation process?

I've tried a basic deep link URL like `https://fakedomain.org/upload` as well as using the `?link=https://fakedomain.org/upload` param and neither seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it is possible to persist the link after installs but it won't be %100 successful because of some limitations on the iOS side. You can check the flowcharts in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/operating-system-integrations)

There could be a couple of reasons for it not to work after the app installation. Since no code is provided I'll assume you are listening to the dynamic link with `onLink` for the app's active state and checking the initial link with `getInitialLink` when your app is in the quit state.

- Persisting the link after app installation involves the clipboard in iOS so make sure the problem is not related to new iOS 16 copy/paste permissions.
- Your navigation library might be trying to navigate to the route from the link before your navigation stack is initialized.
- If the problem occurs only in one platform it might indicate a problem in your native setup like maybe related to `LinkingManager` etc.
- If you are using a custom domain, you should double check your `Associated Domains` and `AndroidManifest` settings.